# postProcessAfterInitialization called twice for sessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

**can somebody tell me why postProcessAfterInitialization method called twice for creating Session Factory in spring and hibernate**

i expected that method called once

this is configuration part of my code and using annotation instead of xml base config

code:

---

```
package org.example.excel.Configuration;

import org.example.excel.ClassFactory.ClassBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private ClassBuilderFactory classBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public HibernateConfig(ClassBuilderFactory classBuilderFactory) {
        this.classBuilderFactory = classBuilderFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("org.example.excel.Model");
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");
        dataSource.setUsername("Test");
        dataSource.setPassword("1234");
        return dataSource;
    }

    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "org.hibernate.context.internal.JTASessionContext");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager tr = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        tr.setSessionFactory(sessionFactoryBean().getObject());
        return tr;
    }
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("in before" + beanName);
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("in after " + beanName);
        return bean;

    }
}
```

---

postProcessAfterInitialization method called once for every bean but called twice for sessionfactory
why?

Comment: Not without seeing your code/configuration. If it is called twice, it is probably instantiated twice.

Comment: thank you @M.Deinum , i added code to this question

Comment: Don't make your `@Configuration` a `BeanPostProcessor` make that a separate bean. Also is it **really** called twice? Or do you think it is called twice? The `LocalSessionFactoryBean` is a `FactoryBean` that produces another bean (the `SessionFactory`). So what I think you are seeing is one invocation for the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` and one for the `SessionFactory`.

Comment: yes,it called twice ,

Comment: And you only answered the first part of the question/comment. Why do people always stop reading after the first sentence?

Comment: dear @M.Deinum , you only ask question in first part and i agree with you for the second part

Comment: Instead of only printing the `beanName` print the type `bean.getClass()` as well. That gives you more information (and probably explain for which bean stuff is being invoked, probably proving my second point).